# If I use NC contact, could I avoid oxidation on the contact?

Tags: switches, switching

If I use the NC contact of a limit switch for micro load switching(24 V, <0.1 mA), could I avoid oxidation on the contact?

Because the contact will be closed and air will not reach it.

I have to use a silver plated limit switch (with NO, NC).

Comment: Manufacturers will usually specify a minimum or ‘wetting’ current. This current is intended to overcome oxidisation. If the contact material is very susceptible to oxidisation, the switch is usually hermetically sealed like a reed switch. Follow the manufacturer’s suggestions and requirements. If in doubt, contact the manufacturer.

Comment: Besides, relay contacts are [coated](https://www.findernet.com/en/uk/news/relay-contact-materials-does-it-matter/) with materials that increase their lifespan preventing oxidation and minimising electric arcs, like Silver Tin Oxide

Answer (score 1):

It would be advisable to use the limit switch contact to switch a relay with gold-plated contacts for micro load switching.

The limit switch contact would switch the relay coil (current ~ 35 mA @ 24 V DC).

Comment: But i did to use silver plate now. Which one would be better? NO or NC

Comment: We use to be sure we had at least 1mA through the contacts, never had any problems. Our systems were industrial 24V systems with control lines run through plastic plants.

Comment: @Ahn JIn Ho - Hi, The contact resistance of a normally-open contact would be less than that of a normally-closed contact since the magnetic force on the former would be higher than the spring force on the latter.

Comment: @Gil - Hi, In my experience, a standard limit switch driving a relay with gold contacts was a highly-reliable combination to switch micro loads.

Comment: Yes gold is better but expensive. I use the pull up and switch to ground, there is no current except when the switch is closed. I use something in the 20K range as a pull up resistor to 24V that connects to maybe 100K to port pin. The junction of the two resistors goes to the switch which pulls it low when activated. You can put a small cap at the port input to debounce and beef up the ESD protection.

Comment: Got it, Gil, thank you.